# Call method after bean initialization but before @Bean called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration extends MyBaseAppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyDAOBean getMyDAOBean() {
        boolean isEmpty = myString.isEmpty();
        return new MyDAOBean();
    }
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="hey")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyBean {
    private String myString;
}


public class MyBaseAppConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    protected String myString;

    //I need some annotation to call this (@PostConstruct maybe?)
    public void setMyString() {
        this.myString= myBean.getMyString();
    }
}
```

I want to set `myString` with something that I got from `myBean`. So I need some annotation to call method that I set this field after myBean initiliazed but before `getMyDAOBean` called. `@PostConstruct` currently working for this situation but I need to be sure if it is always working. Does it do the job or there is something I don't know and this is risky?

Please ignore simplicity of example. `myBean.getMyString()` in `getMyDAOBean` would be more easy but It's more complex in real, just focus on the problem.

Edit: How about setter-injection way? Does it make any difference? More safety or else?

```
public class MyBaseAppConfiguration {
    protected String myString;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyString(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myString= myBean.getMyString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what would be the reason for getting the value of `myString` in `MyBaseAppConfiguration` ? and how is it related to the creation of the bean `MyDAOBean`? Does the creation of the bean 'MyDAOBean' depends on the value of `myString`? if yes, how so?

Comment: @atish.s I made a note at the end of the question just for this. I can't explain the business logic behind that I really trying to write. Focusing on the problem will make things easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add MyBean as a constructor injection.

```
public class MyBaseAppConfiguration {
    protected String myString;

    @Autowired
    public MyBaseAppConfiguration(MyBean myBean ){
      myString = myBean.getMyString();
    }
```

}

Comment: So every child has to create matching constructor super? You gave me an idea actually. How about setter-injection. Editted my post

Answer (score 1):

The creation of the bean for `MyDAOBean` seems to have some dependency on a computed value based on the property of `MyBean`.

The [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation alongside a custom condition can be used to do the operations required; `myString.isEmpty()` is this case.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MyStringIsEmpty implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // Get the spring bean for MyBean
        MyBean myBean = Objects.requireNonNull(context.getBeanFactory()).getBean(MyBean.class);
    
        // Get the property of myString
        String myString = myBean.getMyString();
    
        // perform your desired evaluation
        boolean isEmpty = myString.isEmpty();
    
        return isEmpty; // if true, the bean will be created
    }
}
```

Using the custom condition.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;

@Bean
@Conditional(MyStringIsEmpty.class)
public MyDAOBean getMyDAOBean() {
    return new MyDAOBean();
}
```